# Error SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

My script used to migrate data from SQLite to Postgres in Python. I'm using `threading` module to speed up transfer tables but I got error `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.` Can someone help me edit it? Thanks.
My script :

```
import psycopg2, sqlite3, sys
import time
import threading

sqdb="C://Users//duongnb//Desktop//Python//SqliteToPostgreFull//testmydb6.db"
sqlike="table"
pgdb="testmydb13"
pguser="postgres"
pgpswd="1234"
pghost="127.0.0.1"
pgport="5432"

consq=sqlite3.connect(sqdb)
cursq=consq.cursor()


tabnames=[]
cursq.execute('''SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" AND name LIKE "'''+sqlike+'''%";''')
tabgrab = cursq.fetchall()
for item in tabgrab:
    tabnames.append(item[0])
print(tabgrab)

def copyTable(table):
    cursq.execute("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = ?;", (table,))
    create = cursq.fetchone()[0]
    cursq.execute("SELECT * FROM %s;" %table)
    rows=cursq.fetchall()
    colcount=len(rows[0])
    pholder='%s,'*colcount
    newholder=pholder[:-1]

    try:

        conpg = psycopg2.connect(database=pgdb, user=pguser, password=pgpswd,
                               host=pghost, port=pgport)
        curpg = conpg.cursor()
        curpg.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s;" %table)
        create = create.replace("AUTOINCREMENT", "")
        curpg.execute(create)
        curpg.executemany("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s);" % (table, newholder),rows)
        conpg.commit()

        if conpg:
            conpg.close()

    except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
        print ('Error %s' % e) 
        sys.exit(1)

    finally:
        print("Complete")

consq.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    for table in tabnames:
        p = threading.Thread(target = copyTable, args = (table,))
        p.start()
    for table in tabnames:
        p.join()
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print("Duration {duration} seconds ")
```

My error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\duongnb\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\duongnb\Desktop\Python\SqliteToPostgreFull\MigrateThreading.py", line 25, in copyTable
    cursq.execute("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = ?;", (table,))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread. The object was created in thread id 9744 and this is thread id 12712.
```

Comment: You need to connect to the database in each thread. You can not share a connection between threads.

Comment: @DanD. Can you edit it? Please. I don't know what to do. I think I just have one thread.

Comment: @BinhDuong ***"I think I just have one thread."***: You have **two**, the first is the `"__main__"` thread, the second is `.Thread(target=copyTable ...`

Comment: @stovfl Oh, so I just need to remove `if __name__ == "__main__":` statement, isn't it? Can you show me any other way ?

Comment: ***"I just need to remove"***: Removing `if __name__...` does not remove the allways started `"__main__"' thread. Rethink about the term ***main***. You have to follow the advice from the ***sqlite3.ProgrammingError***.